# How to cancel tool execution in python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I've written a python function that calls a tool (Import CAD to GDB) in a loop. When I run it I have seen that it hangs sometimes, and I have to force the script to quit. I am wondering if there is a way to kill the tool execution after a certain amount of time, and move on to the next item in the loop? Here is what I have so far - I've included a timer but it still hangs:

```
import os, arcpy, arcgisscripting, time, sys
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

def ConvertCADtoGDB(srch_dir,gdb_dir,timeout):
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(srch_dir):
        for file in files:
            f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            in_dgn = dirpath+'\\'+file
            out_gdb = gdb_dir+'\\'+f_name+'.gdb'
            if f_ext == '.dgn':
                if not os.path.isdir(out_gdb):
                    start = time.time()
                    end = start + timeout
                    while time.time() < end:
                        print 'creating',out_gdb
                        gp.ImportCAD_conversion(in_dgn,out_gdb,'','Explode_Complex')
```

Comment: The `time.time() < end` will calculate the time when it starts that `while` loop, but not continue checking it while `ImportCAD_conversion` is running.

Comment: I know i have discovered this when running it. So I was thinking if there was a way to stop the tool execution.. the question is how do i stop it once it starts and hangs?

Comment: I don't think it's exactly hanging -- the import process is still running, but taking a very long time and not providing any visible feedback that it hasn't crashed.

Comment: I've checked the file that it hangs on, very small uncomplicated file, so shouldn't take long at all. When I run it through the CADtoGeodatabase tool goes very quick. I am using ImportCADtoGeodatabase which is a deprecated tool but it gives the option to explode complex features which I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.  The code below creates a separate process to run the ImportCAD_conversion tool in, waits for it to complete and terminates it if the timeout is exceeded.

Note the use of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` syntax, which is [required on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

```
import os, arcpy, arcgisscripting, time, sys
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

def ConvertCADtoGDB(in_dgn,out_gdb):
    gp.ImportCAD_conversion(in_dgn,out_gdb,'','Explode_Complex')
    if not arcpy.Exists(out_gdb):raise RuntimeError('%s does not exist'%out_gdb)

def main(srch_dir,gdb_dir,timeout):
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(srch_dir):
        for f in files:
            f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            in_dgn = os.path.join(dirpath,f)
            out_gdb = os.path.join(gdb_dir,f_name+'.gdb')
            if f_ext == '.dgn':
                if not os.path.isdir(out_gdb):
                    print 'creating',out_gdb
                    #####################################################
                    # Create a separate process to run the tool in
                    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=ConvertCADtoGDB,
                                                args=(in_dgn,out_gdb))
                    p.start()
                    p.join(timeout)   # Wait for process to complete
                    if p.is_alive():  # Terminate process if it is 
                        p.terminate() # still running after the timeout
                        print('Conversion of %s terminated'%in_dgn)
                    else:
                        print('Conversion of %s successful'%in_dgn)
                    #####################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    srch_dir=r'C:\Temp\dgns'
    gdb_dir=r'C:\Temp\gdbs'
    timeout=5 #Seconds
    main(srch_dir,gdb_dir,timeout)
```

Comment: Now I have been running this in my script, but I am noticing that everything is terminating. I have set a time limit of 30 seconds and I have tested on some of the drawings outside of the script, they were sucessfully converted within that time. Wonder what is wrong?

Comment: update: it does seem to work now, though interestingly only after I upped the timeout to 60 seconds. I wonder why it would take longer when run from the script, vs running the tool in arcmap? I also wonder if I have to wait the full 60 seconds, if the tool can complete in a shorter amount of time?

Comment: @kflaw If the tool completes in less than the timeout, you don't have to wait the full 60 sec (or whatever the timeout is). Running the tool in a separate process will take longer than in ArcMap or in the same python process as the new python process has to load arcpy again every time.

Comment: I see that makes sense. So if it takes less than the timeout it will move to next item before the timeout finishes? another thing is that I can't get the files to write out, though it is printing that they are. I thought maybe because I need a return statement in the ConvertCADtoGDB function but that wasn't it.

Comment: @kflaw correct. Also the tool help says the output gdb is temporary so it maybe getting deleted when the subprocess completes

Comment: i don't see how the output gdb is temporary?

Comment: @kflaw, the help says "the resulting data from this function is typically temporary" which is a bit ambiguous. Have you tried testing if the output gdb/tables exist after the tool completes and before the ConvertCADtoGDB process exits?

Comment: Oh I see, typically the data does get written out to disk, whether or not it is intermediate data. I have checked for the output gdbs while the tool is running and each time if moves on to the next file in the loop and I can't find the files. If I run the function without the multiprocessing subprocess, I can find the output on disk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15884/discussion-between-kflaw-and-luke).

Comment: @kflaw I don't think I can help with why you get no output.  Maybe time for a new question?