# How to write output from subprocess to disk (using multiprocessing)

Tags: python, arcpy, parallel-processing, subprocess

This code was developed from another question I posted about how to kill an arcpy tool if it takes longer than a specified time. See [How to cancel tool execution in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106791/how-to-cancel-tool-execution-in-python). Using the multiprocssing module as a subprocess of the function seems to work, the only problem is i can't see how to write the output to disk. The function specifies a path to write the data to, and when I run the function without the subprocess, I can see the files on disk. But when the subprocess is included it doesn't look the files are being written out to disk. Can anyone help?

```
import os, arcpy, arcgisscripting, time, sys
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

def ConvertCADtoGDB(in_dgn,out_gdb):
    gp.ImportCAD_conversion(in_dgn,out_gdb,'','Explode_Complex')
    if not arcpy.Exists(out_gdb):raise RuntimeError('%s does not exist'%out_gdb)

def main(srch_dir,gdb_dir,timeout):
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(srch_dir):
        for f in files:
            f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            in_dgn = os.path.join(dirpath,f)
            out_gdb = os.path.join(gdb_dir,f_name+'.gdb')
            if f_ext == '.dgn':
                if not os.path.isdir(out_gdb):
                    print 'creating',out_gdb
                    #####################################################
                    # Create a separate process to run the tool in
                    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=ConvertCADtoGDB,
                                            args=(in_dgn,out_gdb))
                    p.start()
                    p.join(timeout)   # Wait for process to complete
                    if p.is_alive():  # Terminate process if it is 
                        p.terminate() # still running after the timeout
                        print('Conversion of %s terminated'%in_dgn)
                    else:
                        print('Conversion of %s successful'%in_dgn)
                    #####################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    srch_dir=r'C:\Temp\dgns'
    gdb_dir=r'C:\Temp\gdbs'
    timeout=5 #Seconds
    main(srch_dir,gdb_dir,timeout)
```

**UPDATE:**

I tested Luke's code, and the message I receive tellS me the process was successful, but still I get nothing written out to disk:

```
import os, arcpy, arcgisscripting, time, sys
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.queues import SimpleQueue
copy_dir = r'D:\test3'
gdb_dir = copy_dir+'\\'+'CAD_Export_to_GDB'

def ConvertCADtoGDB(msgs,in_dgn,out_gdb):
    try:
        gp = arcgisscripting.create()
        gp.ImportCAD_conversion(in_dgn,out_gdb,'','Explode_Complex')
        if not arcpy.Exists(out_gdb):raise RuntimeError('%s does not exist'%out_gdb)
        msgs.put(gp.GetMessages())
    except Exception as err:
        msgs.put(gp.GetMessages())
        msgs.put(err)

def main(srch_dir,gdb_dir,timeout):
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(srch_dir):
        for f in files:
            f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            in_dgn = os.path.join(dirpath,f)
            out_gdb = os.path.join(gdb_dir,f_name+'.gdb')
            if f_ext == '.dgn':
                if not os.path.isdir(out_gdb):
                    print 'creating',out_gdb
                    #####################################################
                    # Create a separate process to run the tool in
                    # and a Queue to pass messages back
                    m = SimpleQueue()
                    p = Process(target=ConvertCADtoGDB,
                                   args=(m,in_dgn,out_gdb))
                    p.start()
                    p.join(timeout)   # Wait for process to complete
                    err = None
                    while not m.empty(): # Check if messages in queue
                        msg = m.get()
                        if isinstance(msg, Exception):err= msg
                        else: print msg
                    if p.is_alive():  # Terminate process if it is
                        p.terminate() # still running after the timeout
                        print('terminated')
                    elif err:
                        print('unsuccessful: %s'%err)
                    else:
                        print('successful')
                    #####################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    srch_dir=r'C:\Temp\dgns'
    gdb_dir=r'C:\Temp\gdbs'
    timeout=60 #Seconds
    main(copy_dir,gdb_dir,timeout)
```

Comment: I think this might be better addressed in Stack Overflow.

Comment: It might be worth checking the process [exitcode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.exitcode). If  it's not 0 then the process has raised an error and hasn't successfully completed.

Comment: @kflaw what is the _complete_ output from the script, it should not just output "successful". And you don't seem to have changed `srch_dir=r'C:\Temp\dgns'` and `gdb_dir=r'C:\Temp\gdbs'` to your actual paths...

Comment: @kflaw you have defined some variables outside the `if __name__=='__main__':` block. Don't do that. As I stated in my [other answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/107466/2856) the use of the `if __name__=='__main__':` syntax is [required on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

Comment: I see, making sure the variables used were in the if __name__=='__main__': block did the trick. I need to better understand that. Thanks so much for all your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably getting some sort of exception being raised. Perhaps use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue) to pass messages back to the parent process.

**Tested working code:**

```
import os, arcpy, arcgisscripting, time, sys
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.queues import SimpleQueue

def ConvertCADtoGDB(msgs,in_dgn,out_gdb):
    try:
        gp = arcgisscripting.create()
        gp.ImportCAD_conversion(in_dgn,out_gdb,'','Explode_Complex')
        if not arcpy.Exists(out_gdb):raise RuntimeError('%s does not exist'%out_gdb)
        msgs.put(gp.GetMessages())
    except Exception as err:
        msgs.put(gp.GetMessages())
        msgs.put(err)

def main(srch_dir,gdb_dir,timeout):
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(srch_dir):
        for f in files:
            f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            in_dgn = os.path.join(dirpath,f)
            out_gdb = os.path.join(gdb_dir,f_name+'.gdb')
            if f_ext == '.dgn':
                if not os.path.isdir(out_gdb):
                    print 'creating',out_gdb
                    #####################################################
                    # Create a separate process to run the tool in
                    # and a Queue to pass messages back
                    m = SimpleQueue()
                    p = Process(target=ConvertCADtoGDB,
                                       args=(m,in_dgn,out_gdb))
                    p.start()
                    p.join(timeout)   # Wait for process to complete
                    err = None
                    while not m.empty(): # Check if messages in queue
                        msg = m.get()
                        if isinstance(msg, Exception):err= msg
                        else: print msg
                    if p.is_alive():  # Terminate process if it is
                        p.terminate() # still running after the timeout
                        print('terminated')
                    elif err:
                        print('unsuccessful: %s'%err)
                    else:
                        print('successful')
                    #####################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    srch_dir=r'C:\Temp\dgns'
    gdb_dir=r'C:\Temp\gdbs'
    timeout=60 #Seconds
    main(srch_dir,gdb_dir,timeout)
```

**The output is:**

```
creating C:\Temp\gdbs\smalltest.gdb
Executing: ImportCAD C:\Temp\dgns\smalltest.dgn C:\Temp\gdbs\smalltest.gdb # Explode_Complex
Start Time: Thu Jul 24 09:37:42 2014
...Importing layers from C:\Temp\dgns\smalltest.dgn
...Importing entities from C:\Temp\dgns\smalltest.dgn
......4 entities imported from C:\Temp\dgns\smalltest.dgn
...Importing and consolidating extended data to separate table
Succeeded at Thu Jul 24 09:37:46 2014 (Elapsed Time: 4.00 seconds)
successful
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested your code and it printed 'successful', but no files have been written out to disk.

Comment: @kflaw please edit your question to show the new code you ran

Comment: i added the code but its just the same as your except i inserted my function - I don't know how useful that is. I am a bit beyond my limits with this

Comment: i took the code away, it was redundant. As I mentioned I didn't change anything except inserting my own function